# Multiple arguments in a google Text to Speech api html GET request

Tags: html, get, google-text-to-speech

I have a GET request in my code that gets an mp3 file from google's text to speech API. the request goes something like this.

```
api/getlink?word=testing
```

But I want to have multiple arguments in this request. Like a speakingRate argument. I have tried

```
api/getlink?word=testing,speakingRate=0.5

and

api/getlink?word=testing&speakingRate=0.5
```

but neither seem to work. I'm missing the right formatting or is this method just restricted to a single argument?

Comment: have you try to see [here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech?hl=it)

Comment: yea I know about the documentation but I don't really know where to look I don't really see anything about GET requests.

Comment: why don't use POST